# SQL Server 2005: Round returns incorrect value if I use a float variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

In SQL Server 2005, I am getting incorrect values when I try to round a value stored in a float variable.  In the example below, I expect that both calls to the ROUND function should return 5.6:

```
DECLARE @foo float;
DECLARE @bar float;
DECLARE @baz float;

SET @foo = 5.55;
SET @bar = ROUND(@foo, 1) --> 5.5
SET @baz = ROUND(5.55, 1) --> 5.6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using the `float` datatype for exact `decimal` values.

In this particular case, you could convert your `@foo` variable to a `decimal`:

```
SET @bar = ROUND(CAST(@foo as DECIMAL(10,2)), 1) --> 5.6
```

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)